# Left Join only returning one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, left-join

I am trying to join two tables. I would like all the columns from the `product_category` table (there are a total of 6 now) and count the number of products, CatCount, that are in each category from the `products_has_product_category` table.  My query result is 1 row with the first category and a total count of 68, when I am looking for 6 rows with each individual category's count.

```
<?php
          $result = mysql_query("
                        SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.category_id) AS CatCount
                        FROM `product_category` a
                        LEFT JOIN `products_has_product_category` b
                        ON a.product_category_id = b.category_id
                    ");
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

              echo '
              <li  class="ui-shadow" data-count-theme="d">
              <a href="' . $row['product_category_ref_page'] . '.php" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">' . $row['product_category_name'] . '</a><span class="ui-li-count">' . $row['CatCount'] . '</span></li>';
          }

        ?>
```

I have been working on this for a couple of hours and would really appreciate any help on what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In absence of a `GROUP BY` clause, the `COUNT()` aggregate can only return one row, holding the total count for the table after filtering by the `WHERE` clause.  I suspect you mean to `GROUP BY b.category_id` in  a `LEFT JOIN` against a subquery:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  catcount
FROM
  product_category a
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT category_id, COUNT(*)  AS catcount
    FROM products_as_product_category 
    GROUP BY category_id
  ) subcount ON a.product_category_id = subcount.category_id
```

It is because MySQL is lenient about the contents and presence of the `GROUP BY` clause that your query was syntactically successful in the first place.  It would have failed in most other RDBMS because of a missing `GROUP BY`.  Depending on the contents of your table `product_category`, MySQL may permit you to do the above without the joined subquery, and instead include the correct columns from `product_category` in the `GROUP BY` clause, but without knowing the contents of that table I can't say for sure, and the above method is standard and portable across other RDBMS without relying on MySQL's lenience.

A final note, although I have done it above, I *never* recommend doing `SELECT *` in a `JOIN` query. Common column names between the joined tables require aliases to differentiate in the PHP API, introducing confusion. Always best to be explicit about the columns you actually need in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: I could hug you right now!!!  It worked perfectly.  Thank you for the advice, I will change the select * to the individual column names.  And again, THANK YOU, especially for being so detailed in your answer, I enjoy learning the why's and not just getting the answer!

Comment: @Adam Happy to help. If you ask questions and only get code solutions without explanations (solution + explanation = answer), don't be afraid to press the answerers for an explanation of how & why it works. It improves the overall quality of Stack Overflow, I truly believe.